# What is TDS Protocol Version 8.0 and why should I use it?

Tags: sql-server, freetds

I've been using FreeTDS with 8.0 protocol for some time to connect to a MSSQL Database, and things have worked great.  But, recently, things started to not work so great. I'll spare the details.

So we decided we needed to know a bit more, and I am a bit confused by the following:

[Does FreeTDS support Microsoft servers?](http://www.freetds.org/faq.html#Does.FreeTDS.support.Microsoft.servers)

> Yes. Microsoft servers don't usually accept TDS 5.0 connections. Use
>   one of versions 4.2, 7.0 or 8.0 of the protocol. See the [User Guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)
>   for details.

[User Guide](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm)

```
[No mention of 8.0 anywhere on the page.]
```

So, what is TDS Protocol Version 8.0 and why should I use it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

FreeTDS "version 8" is actually version 7.1. Unfortunately, you have to look at the "[history of TDS versions](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/tdshistory.html)" page to figure that out, but here's the explanation from there:

> Earlier FreeTDS documentation referred to versions 7, 8 and 9. Microsoft subsequently published a protocol specification document denoting 7.1 and 7.2, and one finds scattered references using that scheme elsewhere, too. For that reason, FreeTDS switched to Microsoft's nomenclature.

Comment: The "Microsoft" numbering, 7.2.