# How to connect python to SQL Azure?

Tags: python, azure

I would like to develop an apps using python/webapp2, which is required SQL Azure database hosted in Azure Cloud. How can i connect python to SQL Azure?

Comment: Have you checked [Windows Azure: Python Developer Center](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/)?

Comment: Yes, i did. Can't find any tutorial there. They do have tutorial for MySQL, but SQL Azure.

Comment: [Python App using storage](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-blob-storage/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc) with FreeTDS and format your connection string [as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721403/read-from-the-server-failed-when-trying-to-connect-to-sql-azure-from-tsql):

```
TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net -U Username -D DatabaseName -p 1433 -P Password
```

Also make sure that you configure SQL Azure correctly in order to allow your IP to access the database.