# Rails and Azure: TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, azure, activerecord, tiny-tds

I'm trying to configure my Rails project with SQL on Azure. I'm using Mac OS X 10.11.

This is part of my `config/database.yml`:

```
staging:
  adapter: sqlserver 
  mode: dblib 
  host: db-staging.database.windows.net
  port: 1433 
  database: db-staging
  username: myuser@db-staging
  password: mypass
  timeout: 5000
  azure: true
```

When I run `tsql` seems like is everything ok:

```
$ tsql -H db-staging.database.windows.net -U myuser -P 'mypass' -v -p 1433 -D db-staging
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
Setting db-staging as default database in login packet
Changed database context to 'db-staging'.
Changed language setting to us_english.
1>
```

But when I run `rake db:migrate` I receive this error `TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed`.

Here is the complete trace:

```
$ rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging --trace                                                                      
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

  * development - set it to false
  * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
  * production - set it to true

** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
rake aborted!
TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:74:in `connect'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tiny_tds-0.7.0/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:74:in `initialize'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:311:in `new'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:311:in `dblib_connect'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:302:in `connect'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:58:in `initialize'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:17:in `new'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-4.2.10/lib/active_record/sqlserver_base.rb:17:in `sqlserver_connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:912:in `initialize'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:819:in `new'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:819:in `up'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/migration.rb:797:in `migrate'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `call'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:248:in `block in execute'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `each'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `execute'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/task.rb:173:in `invoke'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/monteirobrena/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I saw other questions like this, but did not help me:

[TinyTds::Error: Adaptive Server connection failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15369304/tinytdserror-adaptive-server-connection-failed)

[TinyTds Error: Adaptive Server connection timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312327/tinytds-error-adaptive-server-connection-timed-out)

[Updated]

I tried do exactly like here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sql-database-samples/tree/master/Ruby%20on%20Rails/Sample%20Mac

Following this post I found the correct configurations to set in my `config/database.yml`.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-ruby-simple-mac-osx/

```
staging:
  adapter: sqlserver
  username: 'username@database'
  password: 'password'
  host: 'db-staging.database.windows.net'
  port: 1433
  database: 'db-staging'
  azure: true
```

And add this gems im my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'
```

Now when I access my project folder and run `rails s` I can connect with my database and everything work fine. But, if I run my project with Puma and Nginx, I receive this error:

```
TinyTds::Error (Adaptive Server connection failed):
```

[/Updated]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need install FreeTDS by myself, if `apt-get` we can't pass the arguments of compilation:

```
wget http://ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/stable/freetds-stable.tgz

$ tar -zxvf freetds-stable.tgz

$ cd freetds-0.91/

$ ./configure --with-tdsver=8.0 --with-openssl=/usr/bin

$ make

$ sudo make install
```

And now I can access my database:

```
$ tsql -C # OK!

$ TDSVER=8.0 tsql -H mydb.database.windows.net -p 1433 -U myuser@mydb -P mypassword -D mydb
```

And everything works when I run and access with Puma, Nginx and Capistrano.

See more here:

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/266

Answer (score 0):

Set you tds_version to 70 in your database.yml. This solved this issue for me.

Thanks.