# Unable to connect to sql server from tsql

Tags: sql-server, macos, t-sql, freetds

I am able to connect to remote sql server using SQLpro for MSSQL. However, When I am trying to use tsql to connect, i am not able to connect to the database

OS: Macos x

My freetds.conf
path: /usr/local/freetds.conf

```
[global]
    # tds protocol
    tds version =8.0

[MyserverName]
    host = sqlservername
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

When I run tsql command it is throwing me an error
commands as follows:

```
tsql -S MyserverName -p 1433 -U username -P password
```

or

```
tsql -H sqlserver -p 1433 _U username -P password
```

Below are the errors, when I tried to play with above commands

```
MSG 18452 (severety 14, state 1):
"Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication"

Error 20002(severity 9):    
"Adaptive Server connection failed"
```

I believe that sqlpro uses jdbc driver to connect to sqlserver, but however, I think this should even work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to add flag -C

Comment: Looking at the [freetds connection properties](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/odbcconnattr.htm), you may want to add Trusted_Connection No, although it appears to default to no. I also found [Read from the server failed when trying to connect to sql-azure from tsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721403/read-from-the-server-failed-when-trying-to-connect-to-sql-azure-from-tsql
) which suggests you may want to specify the TDS version before the tsql command. You may also want to look at [https://gist.github.com/tommct/5749453]( [3]: https://gist.github.com/tommct/5749453).

Comment: Thanks fot the immediete response. But the error is the same. "Login failed. the login trusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication"

Comment: @AndrewO'Brien@Fabiano Carvalho Seems like sqlpro also has freetds inbuilt for it. If I can find that config. Then it can help me.

Comment: But that is also the same.

Answer (score 0):

To connect via `tsql` with Windows authentication, using `DOMAIN` in place of the domain name and `USERNAME` in place of the Windows user, you need to use this format:

`tsql -S yourmssql.server.com -p 1433 -U DOMAIN\\username`

It should then prompt you for a password and log you in. If you enter the wrong domain password, you'll get the 'untrusted domain' error, and if you don't use two backslashes, you'll get this error: `Login failed for user 'DOMAINusername.` followed by `Adaptive Server connection failed`. This has been tested with FreeTDS 0.95 against SQL Server 2014.

If you're still having issues, you may wish to add this to our `freetds.conf` file:

```
ntlmv2 = yes
```

Good luck!

Comment: I tried the above. But the it is throwing me an error
"Login failed. The Login is from untrusted domain and cannot be used with windows authentication".