# azure ubuntu 16.04 VM can't connect to database on azure

Tags: python, mysql, azure, virtual-machine

I trying connect to `mysql` db from `VM`, with `python` driver `pymssql`.

```
_connection = mysql.connect(host="xxxxxx.database.windows.net", user='xxxxxx@xxxxxx',
                                  password='xxxxx', database='xxxxxx')
```

But i get exeption like this

> File "pymssql.pyx", line 641, in pymssql.connect (pymssql.c:10824)
>   pymssql.OperationalError: (20002, b'DB-Lib error message 20002, severity 9:\nAdaptive Server connection failed
>   (my-xxxxx.database.windows.net:1433)\n')

When I connecting to this database from my local pc all good.

P.S. 
I opened all ports for all protocols on my `VM`

Comment: Did you update the firewall on SQL Database to allow for your VM to connect?

Comment: Yes, I cheked it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my experience, Python `pymssql` package is depended on `freetds-common` package which will be installed when using `sudo apt install python-pymssql` command to install it.

And for Azure SQL Database, you need to set the tds version with `7.3`, so please refer to my anser for the other similar SO thread [pymssql: Connection to the database only works sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380367/pymssql-connection-to-the-database-only-works-sometimes/32435770#32435770) to check whether the freetds has been install and what the tds version in the configuration file `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf` is.

Hope it helps.