# Managed Instance Connection Python

Tags: python, azure-sql-database, pymssql, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have been using pymssql for a while with no issues.   I can connect to on-prem and azure sql db.

However, we moved an on-prem db to azure MANAGED Instance and the same scripts don't work after altering the connect server variables.

```
conn = pymssql.connect(host='mysrv-sql.da0b68f6c.database.windows.net', user='myuser', password='mypass',  database='mydb')
conn.autocommit(True)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

I have tried all combinations of the username (with or without @mysrv-sql, @mysrv-sql.da0b..., etc)

I just get the generic: DB-Lib 20002 Error, Adaptive Server connection failed

NOTE: I can connect to the managed instance using TSQL or SSMS on the same machine python is executed.

FYI: Using wheel 2.1.4 with FreeTDS,  I have a feeling the problem is related to Managed Instance forcing Encryption

Comment: Did you review this? http://pymssql.org/en/stable/azure.html

Comment: yes, using that and my binaries and lib, I can connect to an Azure SQL DB no problem, changing the server (using the same user and password that exists and I can login with via SSMS to both Azure SQL and Azure Managed Instance) I get the 20002 error when attempting to connect via python.

Comment: Basically, 
Same user/password in both Azure SQL DB and Azure Managed Instance
Using said password, I can login to Both Azure SQL and Azure Managed from SSMS on machine running python
In python, Using a connection string I can use said username/password and connect to Azure SQL DB
Changing python server to Azure managed fails

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380367/pymssql-connection-to-the-database-only-works-sometimes/32435770#32435770

Comment: yes, I've read them.  Those threads relate to azure sql db which I have no issue connecting to.

Comment: Even if only for diagnostic purposes, can you try connecting via pyodbc with Microsoft's "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server" and see if that works any better?

Comment: As an example using pytds lib  is `pytds.tds_base.Error: Client does not have encryption enabled but it is required
 by server, enable encryption and try connecting again`